# Error::Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, r, classification, random-forest

I am building a classification model using `randomForest`. When trying to predict I get the below error

> Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data

I made sure that the testing and training data has same levels.

I also included

```
levels(test_var) <- levels(train_var)
```

to make sure that the levels are matching.

But still I end up getting this error, is there anything else that I should look for?

`**EDITED ON 3rd Aug 2015**`

> Here is the structure of the training dataset

[image]

> Structure of the test dataset

[image]

> Sapply training data

[image]

> Sapply testing data

[image]

> In order to make sure that the levels are matching between the training and test datasets, I wrote this loop to see if there are any differences exist between the datasets

```
for(i in 1:28) 

 {
   if(is.factor(testing[,i]))
    {

    print(names((testing[i])))
    difference_in_test = setdiff(levels(testing[,i]), levels(training_data[,i]))
      print(difference_in_test)

    }
 }
```

> Results of the above For loop which shows that there are no differences exist between the levels.

```
[1] "VAR1"
character(0)
[1] "VAR2"
character(0)
[1] "VAR3"
character(0)
[1] "VAR4"
character(0)
[1] "VAR5"
character(0)
[1] "VAR7"
```

> I still continue to get the error as mentioned below:

[image]

> Edit on 4th Aug

I started getting the above error only after including a filter in my dataset like this:

training_data <- subset(training_data, gender !="F")

Comment: It would be very useful if you would provide the R package that you are using  and a sample of the data.  My guess is that there are some sort of hidden differences in the features.  Often R data comes in as factors or character strings instead of numbers, so even though they look like numbers, they aren't.  There are several ways to convert to numeric data, but `as.numeric()` is the most popular.  Check out [this stack overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288485/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-column-to-numeric-type)

Comment: @AN6U5- Thanks for the reply. I am using randomForest package. The error i got during the predict statmenet.  I will try to provide some sample data by tomorrow. However I could see that both the training data and the test data contains same factors for categorical data and the few numerical variables.

Comment: I'm still skeptical that either the types are different, the number of features are different, or you are giving it the transpose of your data so the shape is different.  Those are the things I would investigate with that error.

Comment: @AN6U5 - Thank you again. So do you advice to try all the numeric fie lds to be declared as.numeric explicitly ( and the factor fields as as.factor() respectively) and give a try?

Comment: I just want you to run `sapply(data, mode)` and `sapply(data, class)` and `dim(data)` on your training data and testing data to see if everything matches.

Comment: @AN6U5 - Thank you. I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26481/discussion-between-arun-and-an6u5).

Comment: @AN6U5 - As per your suggestion. I tried with sapply functions mentioned above. Everything looks ok for me.                                          But one clue I got from your earlier reply - "or you are giving it the transpose of your data so the shape is different"- Could you please let me know what you mean by this? Actually i started getting this problem only after applying a filter with in the program.   I apply something like this testing_data <- subset(testing_data, var1 != "xyz").. I will explain you a little bit more in the next comment.

Comment: @AN6U5 - I have two R programmes. Let us call it as A & B. Program A does the preprocessing, puts the data into a .csv and saves the file in a location. Program B picks the .csv, builds the model and does the prediction job. Everything was working fine for me, until i applied the above said filter to the data, that is, testing_data <- subset(testing_data, var1 != "xyz"). As you said that "transposing  could have reshaped the data", I suspect that this subset filter could be causing some issue. Could you please advice me how can i find what is making this problem please?

Comment: @AN6U5 - Do you have any other thoughts on this please?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information yet for people to help you. Please provide some data and your code.

Comment: @AN6U5 - Sorry for the delay. I have now the added the required infoarmtion.